# Compile time error stating that I need to pass "int" type data, while performing add() operation on a List<Edge<T>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, graph

I am working on a application(JAVA application) which uses Graph as its basic data structure. I implemented the graph using java Collection.
I made a List as

```
List<Edge<T>> list=new ArrayList<Edge<T>>();
```

then I pass values as `list.add(e1,e2);` where e1 and e2 are of Edge type.
But the compiler is giving an incompatible type error, stating that Edge cannot be converted to int.
Can some one please help me understand the reason behind it, as every where else I used add() in my program it worked just fine. 
The problematic method along eith the Edge class is given below.

```
    public void removeTr(){
        for(Vertex<T> v1:vertices){
            Iterator<Edge<T>> itr=v1.out.iterator();
            List<Edge<T>> list=new ArrayList<Edge<T>>();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Edge<T> e1=itr.next();
                Vertex<T> v2=e1.getTo();
                Iterator<Edge<T>> iter=v2.out.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    Edge<T> e2=iter.next();
                    Vertex<T> v3=e2.getTo();
                    if(v3!=null){
                        list.add(e1,e2);//THIS IS THE ERROR MAKING STATEMENT
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            minimizeTr((ArrayList<Edge<T>>)list);
        }

    }



  class Edge<T>{
    int cost;
    Vertex<T> gIn;
    Vertex<T> gOut;
    public Edge(Vertex<T> from, Vertex<T> to, int cost){
        this.cost=cost;
        gOut=from;
        gIn=to;
        from.setOut(this);
        to.setIn(this);
    }
    public Vertex<T> getFrom(){
        return gOut;
    }
    public Vertex<T> getTo(){
        return gIn;
    }
    public void appendCost(int c){
        this.cost=this.cost+c;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think that `add` should do? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains because there is no method `add(E, E)` defined in `java.util.List<E>`. The closest method the compiler can find for the given arguments in your code is `add(int index, E e)`, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

So the compiler assumes that you want to call the 2-parameter method `add(int, E)`, but your first argument is not of type `int` but of type `Edge`, which is why you are getting this error.